# Non-Latin numerals with Polyglossia and the exam class [XeLaTeX]

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, exam

I am writing an exam with exam class and Polyglossia.

For some reason the Hebrew numerals are produced with an apostrophe at the exam list.

I need the numerals to be without the apostrophe or as in the regular list I produced with the enumerate command.

I have also noticed that the **third** numbered item is not in line with the other numbered items.

MWE:

```
%:Preamble
%:Class
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, ansers]{exam}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
%:Language
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=hebrewnumeral]{hebrew}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{David CLM}
\usepackage{bidi}
%:Start
\begin{document}
\section{\textlang{english}{Bad List}}
\begin{questions}
\setcounter{question}{0}
\question א
\begin{choices}
\choice 1
\CorrectChoice 2
\choice 3
\choice 4
\choice 5
\end{choices}
\end{questions}
\section{\textlang{english}{Good List}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item א
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\item 5
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to number formatting, add the following:

```
\renewcommand\choicelabel{(\alph{choice})}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how to align the numerals to the right rather than left?